# Integration of svg-edit or other programs on Laravel 4

Tags: php, svg, laravel, laravel-4, svg-edit

I'm trying to integrate [svg-editor](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html) with Laravel 4.

My current solution is to insert svg-editor.html file renamed as svg-editor.php inside my views folder and move the rest of files into the public folder. So now I've moved all the calls to js and css files into the edit view and all points to the public folder to let laravel load the needed files for svg-editor. js and css files are into assets folder and I call them with asset function:

```
<script>{{{ asset('/assets/js/ *original path from svg-editor* ') }}}</script>
```

**public folder structure**

- app
- public
- vendor
- svg-edit-2_6

**Views folder:** inside svg-edit-2_6 there's just svg-editor.php to be able to include on template with @include()

Of course this solution is messy because I've to modify all calls inside svg-editor code such as paths and URLs references. My question is if there's any way to let laravel to load this program without having to modify its params. I think could be possible to make some kind of calls froms start.php file but I could not find information about how to do this.

Could it be possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I haven't used Laravel, but I integrated SVG-Edit in a Rails app by placing it in the `public` directory and then placing it in an `iframe`. SVG-Edit provides an API to control it from outside the iframe.

Comment: OMG! just as easy as you told... thanks!!  :D

Comment: @Duopixel I also need to integrate it in rails can you please explain me in detail,what if I want to keep source code with me?

Comment: @SachinPrasad웃 What do you mean by "keep the source code with you"?

Comment: @Duopixel What I mean is I want all the codes(js,css,images) to be on my server. Btw I found this gem https://github.com/lml/sketchily should I use it?

Comment: If you drop svg-edit into your `public` folder it just works and you keep all your assets in your server. Sketchily looks handy but I wouldn't use it if I were to customize SVG Edit's code.